# Check for duplicate arrays in buffer

Tags: c, arrays, duplicates

I am working on an embedded system in which a packet is saved if the device cannot establish a communication. I have many different scenarios where the packet can be saved and I want to avoid saving repeated packages.

The packets of the system are 16 bytes long and I store them in a buffer of 320 bytes (in order to keep 20 packages maximum).

How can I check if the packet I am about to save is repeated somewhere in the buffer?

Comment: Simply loop over the "buffer" you have and check if the package exists? Even on a very small embedded system it's going to be fast enough to do multiple times a second. As for the "check", it really depends on what you "packets" are.

Comment: Do the packets include a checksum? If so, perhaps you could use that to check for duplicates.

Comment: @DavidCollins Depends on the size of the checksum. Because the birthday paradox might cause a problem there. And normal checksums are not build to withstand dublication attacks. A hash would be better but it might be to expensive.If a occasional lost package would not be a problem this would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through saved packets and compare them with the new one to be added

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// represents a 16 char packet
typedef char packet_t[16];

/* pktbuf library - used to store up to 20 packet_t packets */

struct pktbuf_s {
    packet_t buffer[20];
    size_t packetcnt;
};

#define PKTBUF_INIT()  {0}

int pktbuf_save(struct pktbuf_s *t, packet_t *packet)
{
    assert(t != NULL);
    assert(packet != NULL);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < t->packetcnt; ++i) {
        if (!memcmp(&t->buffer[i], packet, sizeof(*packet))) {
            // duplicate packet found in buffer, notify user application
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (t->packetcnt == sizeof(t->buffer)/sizeof(*t->buffer)) {
        // no place in buffer, notify user
        return -1;
    }
    // save the packet and increment packet count
    memcpy(&t->buffer[t->packetcnt], packet, sizeof(*packet));
    t->packetcnt++;
    // succcess
    return 0;
}

void pktbuf_clear(struct pktbuf_s *t)
{
    assert(t != NULL);
    t->packetcnt = 0;
}

size_t pktbuf_get(struct pktbuf_s *t, packet_t **packets)
{
    assert(t != NULL);
    *packets = t->buffer;
    return t->packetcnt;
}

/* User application example ----------------------------------- */

void packet_receive(packet_t *packet)
{
    memset(packet, 1, sizeof(*packet));
}

int main()
{
    struct pktbuf_s pktbuf = PKTBUF_INIT();

    // some user app receives packet
    packet_t packet;
    packet_receive(&packet);
    // save received packet in bnuffer
    if (pktbuf_save(&pktbuf, &packet) == -1) {
        // no place in buffer to save the packet
        // print error message? blink with the led? or just ignore?
    }
    // continue the user application, until we want to...

    // drain packet buffer
    packet_t *packets;
    const size_t packetscnt = pktbuf_get(&pktbuf, &packets);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < packetscnt; ++i) {
        // do smth with packet: packets[i]
    }
    // clear buffered packets
    pktbuf_clear(&pktbuf);

    // continue with user application

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### Packet identifiers / Sequence number

It is difficult to give relevant advice without knowing the packet structure or intended purpose. E.g., is this an RS485 network? UART communication with a single device? Something else?

However, if you have control over the packet structure, you could use **a packet identifier** or **sequence number**. If you are only communicating with one device, this alone may be sufficient to discriminate between packets. The packet structure might look something like the following. The relevant field here is *seq no.* (sequence number). Numbers indicate byte offsets.

```
0         1         2     3      15
---------------------------------------------------
| control | seq no. | len | data | checksum / crc |
---------------------------------------------------
           ^^^^^^^^^
```

If there are multiple devices, your packet probably includes source and address fields. In this case, a combination of the address information and the packet identifier would be adequate.

```
0         1         2        3        4     5      15
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| control | seq no. | source | dest   | len | data | checksum / crc |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The onus would be on the device generating the packet to *increment the sequence number for every new packet*. Since your buffer can only hold 20 packets, a 1-byte ID / sequence field would probably be adequate.

(Sequence numbers can be used for other purposes also, such as checking if a packet has been lost in transit - in which case there will be a 'gap' in the sequence numbers of received packets.)

It is hard to know whether such optimizations are necessary - or whether using a simple `memcmp()` to compare packets is adequate.

Comment: The network we are developing is a private network with own protocol stack. We use multiple devices in the network so I need something like Kamil posted. Thank you anyway!